# Right bootstrap column drops under left column when browser resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two column template that I wish to use, that incorporates an accordion navigation on the left column and content on the right column.

However, when the browser is resized the right column drops to to the left under the navigation column.

I would like to have the left column have a fixed width, and the right column to have a fixed width as well, but I want them to possibly remain responsive, but at the moment its a mess responsively, since I dont know how to fix this :/

I want to avoid using any fixed heights as well, and only try to fix this through media queries if possible.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
/* General styles */

.container {
  background-color: #999999;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  min-width: 1530px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Large desktop */

@media (max-width: 1590px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .accordion.sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .accordion.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
.col-md-10 {
  border-left: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
}
.container .row.header {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff
}
.container .row.header h1 {
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
}
h3 {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h3.inner {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
h4 {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.headers {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.headers h1 {
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.headers p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* ****** NAVIGATION SIDEBAR ********
**********************************
*/

.accordion.sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.panel {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400
}
.panel-group {
  border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff}
  .panel-heading h4.panel-title {
    border-radius: 0; //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff;}
    .panel-heading h4.panel-title a: link {
      margin-left: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px
    }
    .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:active {
      color: #fff
    }
    .panel-heading h4.panel-title a:hover {
      color: #FF5500
    }
    .panel-group .panel+.panel {
      margin-top: 0px !important;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc
    }
    .panel.panel-default.custom .panel-heading {
      background: #fff;
      color: #000;
      border-color: #fff
    }
    .panel-body {
      /* padding-top: 2px !important; padding-bottom: 0px !important; */
      padding: 0px !important;
      border: 0
    }
    .panel-body ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    .panel-body ul li {
      padding: 10px 0 !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      font-size: 1.4em
    }
    .panel-body ul li:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0
    }
    .panel-body ul a {
      color: #1f1f1f
    }
    .panel-body ul li a:link {
      margin-left: 40px !important;
      color: #1f1f1f
    }
    .panel-body ul li a:active {
      color: #fff
    }
    .panel-body ul li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FF5500
    }
    #collapseOne.panel-collapse,
    #collapseTwo.panel-collapse,
    #collapseThree.panel-collapse {
      border: 0 !important;
      padding: 0
    }
    .panel-heading.collapsed {
      background-color: #222222
    }
    /* ******** FORM STYLING ***********
************************************
*/
    .form-horizontal .form-group .custom-label {
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: -10px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: #fff;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .form-control {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      border-color: #4d4d4d;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .input-text {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:hover {
      background-color: #34383C;
      border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
    }
    .form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:focus {
      border: 1px solid #FF5500;
    }
    .form-group.social .col-md-2 {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .form-group.social .col-md-2 .fa-instagram,
    .form-group.social .col-md-2 .fa-twitter {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
    }
    .changePswrd {
      padding: 3px 0 0 12px;
    }
    .changePswrd a:link {
      font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .changePswrd a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FF5500;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img.col-md-2 {
      height: 320px;
      width: 230px;
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb {
      height: 320px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .thumb-img {
      text-align: center;
      width: 130px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .circle {
      width: 130px;
      height: 130px;
      background: #4d4d4d;
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
    }
    .form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .caption {
      width: 100%;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help.col-md-4 {
      width: 200px;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help {
      width: 280px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help p {} .form-group .profile-photo-help a:link {
      color: #FF5500;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .form-group .profile-photo-help a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
    .form-group .create-card-btn .glyphicon-plus {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
    .form-group .input-group.date span.input-group-addon {
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      color: #fff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border-color: none;
    }
    .form-group .input-group.date .form-control.date {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .form-group .strength-delete-btn .glyphicon-minus {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    /*  SUBMISSION BUTTONS */
    .submission {
      background-color: #333333;
      border-top: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
      margin-top: 80px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .submission button {
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      border: none;
    }
    .submission .glyphicon-remove-circle,
    .submission .glyphicon-ok-circle {
      font-size: 1.6em;
      font-weight: 400;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 0 5px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .submission .btn-cancel {
      margin-right: 20px;
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    .submission .btn-save {
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary:hover,
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary.outline:focus,
    .btn-primary:active {
      color: #33a6cc;
      border-color: #fff;
    }
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary:active,
    .submission .action-btns .btn-primary.active {
      border-color: #007299;
      color: #007299;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .btn.outline {
      background: none;
      padding: 12px 22px;
    }
    .btn.outline.upload {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
    }
    .btn.outline.football {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .btn.outline.create-card-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
    }
    .btn.outline.sizing-guide-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
    }
    .btn.outline.strength-delete-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      width: 100%
    }
    .btn.outline.add-result-btn {
      background: none;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline {
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline.strength-delete-btn {
      border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
      color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline:hover,
    .btn-primary.outline:focus,
    .btn-primary.outline:active,
    .btn-primary.outline.active,
    .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
      color: #FF5500;
      border-color: #F47929;
    }
    .btn-primary.outline:active,
    .btn-primary.outline.active {
      border-color: #007299;
      color: #007299;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    /* CUSTOM SUBMISSION BTN VALUES */
    .btn-primary {
      padding: 14px 24px;
      border: 0 none;
    }
    .btn:focus,
    .btn:active:focus,
    .btn.active:focus {
      outline: 0 none;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom-styles.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--  **********************************
    following functionality for the accordion referencing to load individual 
    body of parent links 
   ************************************
  -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 accordion sidebar">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="account2.html" href="#collapseOne">
         Link 1
         </a>
         </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                    <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                      <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseTwo">
         Title 2
         </a>
         </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                    <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                      <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                        <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                          <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseThree">
         Title 3
         </a>
         </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                    <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                      <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseFive">
         Title 4
         </a>
         </h4>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default custom">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseSix">
         Title 5
         </a>
         </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of sidebar -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of row -->

      <div class="container load">
        <div class="col-lg-10">

          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <h2>Page Title</h2>
                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/details" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="inner">General</h3>
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="" placeholder="title" focus>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="headers">
                    <h3>Information</h3>
                    <p>
                      Info titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle</br>
                      titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle
                    </p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="inner">Address</h3>
                    <label for="unit" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">Unit number</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="unitNumber" placeholder="1">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="streetNo" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">Street number</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="streetNumber" placeholder="25">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="streetName" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">Street name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="streetName" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="suburb" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">Suburb</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="suburb" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="zip" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">Postcode</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="zip" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="state" class="col-md-2 control-label custom-label">State</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="state" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>



                  <div class="headers">
                    <h3>Social Networks</h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group social">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <label for="instagram" class="control-label custom-label"><span><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span> Instagram</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="instagram-input" placeholder="instagramhandle">
                    </div>



                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group social">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <label for="twitter" class="control-label custom-label"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span> Twitter</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="twitter-input" placeholder="twitterhandle">
                    </div>


                  </div>

                  <div class="row submission">
                    <div class="form-group btn-block">
                      <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-cancel ">Cancel changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-save">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of form -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of row -->
            <!-- </div> end of container -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

right now you have used mostly col-md-* classes so along with that use some col-sm-* or col-xs-* classes and this will prevent the columns from collapsing

```
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* General styles */
.container {
  background-color: #999999;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  width: 1530px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 981px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .accordion.sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}
.col-xs-10 {
  border-left: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
}
.container .row.header {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fff
}
.container .row.header h1 {
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
}
h3 {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h3.inner {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
h4 {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.headers {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.headers h1 {
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.headers p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* ****** NAVIGATION SIDEBAR ********
    **********************************
    */
.accordion.sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.panel {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400
}
.panel-group {
  border-radius: 0;
  //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff
}
.panel-heading h4.panel-title {
  border-radius: 0;
  //box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #074f68; border: 0; background-color: #fff;
}
.panel-heading h4.panel-title a:link {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px
}
.panel-heading h4.panel-title a:active {
  color: #fff
}
.panel-heading h4.panel-title a:hover {
  color: #FF5500
}
.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc
  /* padding-top: 2px !important; 
  padding-bottom: 0px !important; */
  padding: 0px !importa
}
.panel.panel-default.custom .panel-heading {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #fff
}
.panel-body {
  /* padding-top: 2px !important; 
  padding-bottom: 0px !important; */
  padding: 0px !important;
  border: 0
}
.panel-body ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.panel-body ul li {
  padding: 10px 0 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 1.4em
}
.panel-body ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0
}
.panel-body ul a {
  color: #1f1f1f
}
.panel-body ul li a:link {
  margin-left: 40px !important;
  color: #1f1f1f
}
.panel-body ul li a:active {
  color: #fff
}
.panel-body ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF5500
}
#collapseOne.panel-collapse,
#collapseTwo.panel-collapse,
#collapseThree.panel-collapse {
  border: 0 !important;
  padding: 0
}
.panel-heading.collapsed {
  background-color: #222222
}

/* ******** FORM STYLING ***********
    ************************************
    */
.form-horizontal .form-group .custom-label {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group .form-control {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border-color: #4d4d4d;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group .input-text {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:hover {
  background-color: #34383C;
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group .form-control:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FF5500;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU STYLING */

/* OPTIONAL FOR DROPDOWN CARET */
.dropdown-toggle .caret {
  /* position: absolute; right: 12px; top: calc(50% - 2px); */
  background-image: url('arr.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
}
.form-group.social .col-xs-2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.form-group.social .col-xs-2 .fa-instagram,
.form-group.social .col-xs-2 .fa-twitter {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
.changePswrd {
  padding: 3px 0 0 12px;
}
.changePswrd a:link {
  font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.changePswrd a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF5500;
}
.form-group .placeholder-img.col-xs-2 {
  height: 320px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb {
  height: 320px;
}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .thumb-img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .circle {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.form-group .placeholder-img-thumb .caption {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-group .profile-photo-help.col-xs-4 {
  width: 200px;
}
.form-group .profile-photo-help {
  width: 280px;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-group .profile-photo-help p {}
.form-group .profile-photo-help a:link {
  color: #FF5500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form-group .profile-photo-help a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-group .create-card-btn .glyphicon-plus {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.form-group .input-group.date span.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: none;
}
.form-group .input-group.date .form-control.date {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.form-group .strength-delete-btn .glyphicon-minus {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

/*  SUBMISSION BUTTONS */
.submission {
  background-color: #333333;
  border-top: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.submission button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: none;
}
.submission .glyphicon-remove-circle,
.submission .glyphicon-ok-circle {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 400;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.submission .btn-cancel {
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.submission .btn-save {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.submission .action-btns .btn-primary:hover,
.submission .action-btns .btn-primary.outline:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
  color: #33a6cc;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.submission .action-btns .btn-primary:active,
.submission .action-btns .btn-primary.active {
  border-color: #007299;
  color: #007299;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn.outline {
  background: none;
  padding: 12px 22px;
}
.btn.outline.upload {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
}
.btn.outline.football {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 22px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.btn.outline.create-card-btn {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 22px;
}
.btn.outline.sizing-guide-btn {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 22px;
}
.btn.outline.strength-delete-btn {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 22px;
  width: 100%
}
.btn.outline.add-result-btn {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 22px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.btn-primary.outline {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.btn-primary.outline.strength-delete-btn {
  border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
.btn-primary.outline:hover,
.btn-primary.outline:focus,
.btn-primary.outline:active,
.btn-primary.outline.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #FF5500;
  border-color: #F47929;
}
.btn-primary.outline:active,
.btn-primary.outline.active {
  border-color: #007299;
  color: #007299;
  box-shadow: none;
}

/* CUSTOM SUBMISSION BTN VALUES */
.btn-primary {
  padding: 14px 24px;
  border: 0 none;
}
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 sidebar">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default custom">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="account2.html" href="#collapseOne">Link 1</a>
                    </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default custom">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"  data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseTwo">Title 2</a>
                    </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default custom">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseThree">Title 3</a>
                    </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
                <li><a href=""> sub-link</a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default custom">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseFive">Title 4</a>
                    </h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default custom">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-htmlref="#" href="#collapseSix">Title 5</a>
                    </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of sidebar -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->

    <div class="container load">
      <div class="col-lg-10">

        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <h2>Page Title</h2>
              <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/details" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <h3 class="inner">General</h3>
                  <label for="title" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="" placeholder="title" focus>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="title">
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="headers">
                  <h3>Information</h3>
                  <p>
                    Info titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle
                    <br> titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <h3 class="inner">Address</h3>
                  <label for="unit" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="1">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="streetNo" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="title" placeholder="25">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="streetName" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="streetName" placeholder="title">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="suburb" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="suburb" placeholder="title">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="zip" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="zip" placeholder="title">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="state" class="col-xs-2 col-xs-2 control-label custom-label">title</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" id="state" placeholder="title">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this effect the breakpoint where the dropdown of the column wraps under the left column? I have done this before, and it only effects when the browser is at the 980 breakpoint...Can you do a snippet, because I dont feel this would make a difference...

Comment: I did what you said, but it doesnt make a difference. I have a width of my left column that maybe conflicting, but I need a fixed width on it...Have a look at it here: http://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/GZzqrq?editors=1100

Comment: try the edited answer and see if that is what you want

Comment: hmm that did not work.... I need a fixed 1530px width on my container as well...fixed width for my left column and fixed width for my right column...

Comment: you will be able to get that onlyfixed width of container as 1530px once the screen size is larger than that so if you want you may add an additional media query and in then at that min-width .container width tp be 1530px and left and right to be then widths you want but before that you can let them be auto for the responsive feel